# Android: read html files from external folder and display in webview

Tags: android, html, file, webview

I want to display html files in webview. The html files are placed under this folder of my tab, "file manager/Device storage/Android/webpages.
With this code I'm getting null pointer exception probably I am not passing the path correctly. 
And the second problem I am not getting how to load the webpage in webview.

```
WebView webView = new WebView(this);
WebSettings webSettings = webView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
//webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/K1.html");
//setContentView(webView);

File folder = new File("/FileManager/Home/Devicestorage/Android/webpages");
File[] listOfFiles = folder.listFiles();

for (int i = 0; i < listOfFiles.length; i++) {
    if (listOfFiles[i].isFile()) {           
        if(listOfFiles[i].getName().endsWith(".html")){
            System.out.println("File " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
        }
    } else if (listOfFiles[i].isDirectory()) {
        System.out.println("Directory " + listOfFiles[i].getName());
    }
}
```

Comment: First make sure your path is correct and try to use Environmental class for accessing External storage..and your webview is not attached to any view..

Comment: `"file manager/Device storage/Android/webpages`. That is not an Android path. Where did you get this from?

Comment: `File folder = new ....`. After that statement you should first check if that folder exists. And if not display a toast and return. `if ( !folder.exists() ) {toast folder does not exist;  return;}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know if we can open a file with an absolute path on Android like you did. Here's what I did:

```
File extDir = context.getExternalFilesDir(null);
String root = extDir.toString();
File myFile = new File(root + "/your_path/your_file");
... open myFile for reading ...
```

and you would need the external storage permission in the manifest.

Comment: Thank you. i used your code and i replace my path like this, is it correct           File myFile = new File(root + "/FileManager/Home/Devicestorage/Android/webpages/K1.html/");

Comment: The right way would be "new File(root + "/Android/webpages/K1.html")... That's if "Android" is a root level directory in your SD card

Comment: it still does not work. and my phone does not have an sd card.

Comment: Try replacing "context.getExternalFilesDir(null)" with "context.getFilesDir()". This should point to internal storage.

Comment: now my code this and it executes else block                                                                   File extDir = getFilesDir();
        String root = extDir.toString();
        File myFile = new File(root + "/Android/webpages/K1.html/");
        
        if(myFile.exists()){
         
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

         
        }
        else{
         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "does not exists", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

Comment: "/Android/webpages/K1.html/" should be "/Android/webpages/K1.html" i.e. should not end with slash

Comment: Sorry, but can't be of help here. Taking too long. You might want to Consider using Log.d to see where "root + "/Android/webpages/K1.html/" is pointing to and seeing if the path actually exists on your device. Best! .... Mods: I can't move this longish conversation to chat as I don't have enough privileges yet

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71667/discussion-between-anita-and-shirish-hirekodi).

Comment: i debugged the code and root is pointing to /data/data/mypackagename/K1.html